# Firestore query with not-in and array-contains

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know if I can combine `not-in` and `array-contains` in a query in firestore?

I know it's impossible to combine `not-in` with `array-contains-any`.

This an example of what want to do:

```
await ref.where('User','not-in', [['uid']]).get()
```

Comment: You cannot combine those two calls together. What is your database structure and what is the expected result?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible now it's ok.
I will use another Path thank you.